# Prevent ping logging in Mosquitto server

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Is there any way to prevent PINGREQ and PINGRESP to be logged, keeping all other log_type(s) active?

I'm looking for a way to prevent only ping entries to be logged.

Here is my `mosquitto.conf`:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest syslog
log_type all

connection_messages true
log_timestamp true

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Comment: Update the question to show all the logging config options you have (and what cmd line args you are using)

Comment: Also the default logging level shows connection messages but not ping messages iirc

Comment: @hardillb thanks for the suggestion; I've just added conf file, I actually not using any commands, just found those annoying PINGx entries while inspecting the logs in journalctl

Answer (score 3):

Remove the following from the config file:

```
log_type all
```

Comment: That would only leave with the default log types. I just want to avoid pings

Comment: That's not the question you asked, You asked to keep connection messages and not have pings, removing that line will give you that. Have you tried the other logging levels (`debug, error, warning, notice, information, subscribe, unsubscribe`) to see if they give the mix you want?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't mention `connection_messages` as the only thing to keep in the config. I hope yo don't mind me to rephrase the question. I've upvoted your answer, btw

Comment: be removing `log_type debug` and leaving all others, PINGs are no longer logged. May be that's the best I can do, even when I just wanted to leave pings out. Thanks