# Mosquitto debug level log - How to keep all entries but PINGREQ/PINGRESP

Tags: mosquitto

I discussed [here](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1641/prevent-ping-logging-in-mosquitto-server) how to avoid ping messages in logs. By changing `log_type`(s) in `mosquitto.conf` I found that pings are reported under `DEBUG LEVEL`. I would comment this log type in the conf to avoid pings in log, but sadly `PUBLISH` entries are under the same log level and they are all relevant for me.
So, I wonder if it is there any way to avoid exclusively pings from being logged.

Here is my `mosquitto.conf`:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

#persistence false
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

#log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
log_dest syslog

log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
log_type debug
log_type subscribe
log_type unsubscribe
log_type websockets
#log_type all

connection_messages true
log_timestamp true

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not without editing the code to remove the log statements from the ping handling code and recompiling the broker.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement as you, so I have modified mosquitto v1.5.3 source code, and added a custom `log_type` in `mosquitto.conf`:

```
log_type ping
```

[Source on Git Hub](https://github.com/yurenchen000/mosquitto/commit/61ce98cdcb0297f38c52a47c1d9c6247f713dd37).